Effects of an Exploding Gas Giant
What if Jupiter exploded all of a sudden, from the center out, a la "Krypton"?  Given its apparently rocky core, what would be the effects?  I'm thinking of such possibilities as:

Impacts on neighboring worlds or its own moons
Leftover debris from the (relatively) solid core forming an asteroid belt
Dissipation of the gaseous elements across and beyond the solar
system

Thank you!

You say nevermind the mechanism but the question cannot be answered without said mechanism. Different explosions will have entirely different ejecta and effects on the surroundings. The difference between the outer laters being shedded over centuries or near the speed of light is enormous. If you have something in mind, just include it in the question, and if not give criteria for what sort of mechanism you want it to be.

You have literally redefined all of physics in such a way that planets can randomly explode. How's anyone supposed to say what will happen as a result of such an explosion?

Hello @ajderxsen. This is a great worldbuilding question, but it's very broad and violates the [help/dont-ask]'s book rule (if you can reasonably answer by writing a book, it's off-topic). Note that the third bullet by itself might be a book-length answer. Stack Exchange is designed for you to ask for help solving one specific problem. You might be tempted to think this is one very large and ambiguous problem, but it's actually a lot of little problems (what happens to A? what happens to B? what happens to C?) and that's against the rules. (*Continued*)

... So, to avoid being closed could you (a) reduce this to a single question involving one specific target object (everything else can be derived from that), (b) Explain what the viscosity of your Aether is because without that it's a complete guess as to what will happen and that's well outside Stack Exchange's expectations, (c) tell us which of our solar systems planet's to use as the reference (because this matters!), and (d) tell us whether the planet is exploding on its own (how is irrelevant) from the center out or whether some other (*Continued*)

... event has caused a wave in the Aether that causes the destruction (big difference there! And we'll need to know from what direction in all three dimensions).

And to help you out: You need to ask yourself, "what happens if something explodes underwater in the ocean?" because that's really what you're dealing with. Your Aether might not have the viscosity of water (probably doesn't), but from a practical perspective, that only means that the compression wave's amplitude and dampening are different. I suspect most of your concerns will be resolved just from that analysis.
